# Tournament: Should I call this Button-shove?

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, icm

45 player turbo tournament, 9-handed, 7 places paid, 17 players remain. I am among the top players with 21 BB, average stack is about 10 BB. Only one other player on my table has as many chips, he open-shoves 19 BB from the Button. SB folds, I have QQ in the Big Blind. Do I call?

(My read on him is that he plays fairly aggressive. I put him on Ace-rag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would call there with a range of A-10 suited and above. I would lay down 66 and lower. I know 66 is ahead of a10.

Comment: ATs is probably a fold tbh, likely need AJs+. Close though. That being said, It's not simply enough to be ahead in MTTs, we need to be ahead with enough equity to make up for the times when we do lose. QQ is an obvious snap call though.

Comment: @Jonast92 You made the point why I am asking. Is my QQ ahead enough to justify risking a stack that will get me comfortably in the money? While also having a very good position chip-wise at my table right then? I did snap call, and lost to Ace-rag, which got me thinking.

Comment: 10 places away from the money with 7 paid is still a very long way to go. You could consider folding it on the stone cold bubble, otherwise no.